# TSQL: order by asc without column name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm quite new to SQL Server.  Now I came across a query like this:

```
SELECT country FROM Hovercraft.Orders GROUP BY country ORDER BY ASC
```

There is no column name given in the order by clause. Is this possible? SSMS says no.

Jörg

Comment: It is not possible, you have to put `order_by_expression` in the [**`ORDER BY`** clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx). But ***why*** do you want to do so? How SQL Server should `ORDER BY` which column in this case?

Comment: Where do you _came across_ this query?

Comment: Never had it work for me.

Comment: Tim: It was at an exam test prep for querying SQL Server. (70-461)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's probably a misprint - you have to specify *what* you are ordering by; this can be a column name, an expression or the *number* of a column in the output. It's most likely that the query you have seen was one of the latter, that simply omitted the column number `1` - like so:

```
SELECT country FROM Hovercraft.Orders GROUP BY country ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

- so this would order by the contents of the first column of output (ie. `country`).

Comment: #ERROR!

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I just wanted to be sure that I haven't overlooked someting.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Mahmoud Gamal. But, also, it's possible to write such hack like this -

```
SELECT o.country, const_column = 1 
FROM Hovercraft.Orders o
GROUP BY o.country 
ORDER BY const_column ASC
```

In this case, sorting will be performed, but rows' order will not be changed.

On MS SQL 2005:

[image: Proff for @Martin Smith]

On MS SQL 2012:

[image: Proff for @Martin Smith]

Comment: I don't see any sorting performed when I try `SELECT *, const_column = 1 FROM master..spt_values ORDER BY const_column ASC` (and don't see how this is relevant to the question anyway)

Comment: Please tell, for what set a minus? @Jörg Weigel asked "There is no column name given in the order by clause?", so I wrote query only for example, which sorting a constant value.

Comment: I tested this issue in 2005 server version.

Comment: Partially agree with your comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible !..

Order by clause always require column name or column number .

Would you please response me why you want this kind of situation , I think you are working with dynamic query or else please let me know.

As per SQL Standard this not possible.

Thanks.